# Vercel deployment error | npm ERR! code E404

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my website on vercel it is a regular static portfolio website connected with a headless cms (graphql). I've previously deployed a website on vercel, had some errors but the errors were understandable and I managed to solve them all. However, when I try to deploy my web now it returns errors I cannot understand. I have googled and spent a few hours trying to fix the problems but it resulted in nothing. I'm really curious what the npm ERR! code E404 is.

Full error messages

```
Cloning github.com/Dylanyves/mac-yves (Branch: main, Commit: bf98fa3)
Cloning completed: 410.928ms
Installing build runtime...
Build runtime installed: 2.790s
Looking up build cache...
Build Cache not found
Installing dependencies...
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/find-up/-/find-upy-2%20px-4.1.0.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'find-up@https://registry.npmjs.org/find-up/-/find-upy-2 px-4.1.0.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-05-17T13_28_43_498Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "next-portfolio",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "aos": "^2.3.4",
        "graphql": "^16.5.0",
        "graphql-request": "^4.2.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^1.4.12",
        "next": "12.1.6",
        "react": "18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "18.1.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "eslint": "8.15.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
        "postcss": "^8.4.13",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Framework Preset in the Vercel's Build and Deployment settings.

Go through this [documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/build-step) , this should help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have selected the relevant framework which is Next js